# Where can i change bootstrap grid percentage widths?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

As the question states I would like to know where the percentage widths are being generated from in order to override them if necessary?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

In `bootstrap.css` if combined, else you'll find the grid variables in `bootstrap / less / grid.less` or `bootstrap / less / variables.less`.

You can also override the width's you need with your own css, for example:
`.col-md-3 { width: 20%; }`

Comment: The gutter width and the amount of columns is in the variables.less but the width is done automatically with the LESS in the mixins.less